# .txt->Curl->Pregmetch->Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, curl, preg-match

1)Instead of `http://webiste.com/filename` i want to take the data from the `.txt` file which contains 20374 rows and each row contains different website

for example:

```
website1.com
website2.com
website3.com
etc.
```

2)parse them individually using curl command

3)get the needed data via `preg_match`

4)and final results i want to save to my mysql databse

bellow is the code that i am using at the moment, please advise the solution what needs to be added to achieve this goal ?

```
function curl($url)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: ddosdefend=1d4607e3ac67b865e6c7263260c34e888cae7c56")); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); // The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set). 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$test = curl('http://webiste.com/filename');
preg_match('/<iframe class=\"metaframe rptss\" src="(.*?)"/', $test, $matches);

$test2 = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Read the file into an array with `file("filename", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`, then loop over the array with `foreach`.

Comment: do you mean that you want to curl the 20374 websites ?

Comment: @hassan well actuality this is 20374 pages from one website but idea is the same